# SyntaxError homeModelTemplate angularjS model

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I want to create angularjS model has fromDateSearch and toDateSearch my problem is the browser is show SyntaxError but when I remove it error go away

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token :

```
'use strict';
var homeModelTemplate = function(){
    return
    {
        fromDateSearch: new Date(),
        toDateSearch: new Date()
    };
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

syntax issue, always use return {

}

```
 var homeModelTemplate = function(){
        return {
            fromDateSearch: new Date(),
            toDateSearch: new Date()
        };
    };
```